# What happens if I use extern "C++" with a C toolchain?

Tags: c++, c, extern

My question is mainly about the fact that a C++ toolchain "understands" both C and C++, so if I feed some code with an `extern "C"` to a c++ toolchain I assume it can understand what to do with that; but what if I feed code with `extern "C++"` to a C toolchain ?

What is the expected behaviour ?

Comment: `C` is subset of `C++`... It`s not applicable vice versa

Comment: @Krishna and this is the starting point ... what I'm supposed to do with that kind of code if I have a C compiler ?

Comment: @someone, not entirely true, they are different specifications. For example I believe C++ doesn't support designated initializers currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the compiler ALSO understands C++, it may accept it. If it's a pure C compiler it will object (just like it will on `extern "C"` as that syntax is not valid C - this is why it's typically enclosed with `#ifdef __cplusplus` or some such)

Comment: Formally, it must issue a diagnostic. That's the only requirement.

Answer (score 4):

It is *supposed* to not compile, it is not valid C syntax.

The standard approach to make C declarations in a header file work both in a C and C++ compiler is to rely on a preprocessor symbol that's only defined in a C++ compiler.  Like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// C declarations here
// ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Every C++ compiler defines __cplusplus.

Comment: That is correct, of course, but I don't think it answers OP's question. I think he/she is implicitly asking about calling C++ code from a C translation unit.

Comment: This answer "feeds code with extern "C++" to a C toolchain".  Fairly sure that's what he needs.

Answer (score 4):

`extern "C++"` is not valid C code, so a conforming C compiler must issue a diagnostic. There is no requirement that it not compile the code. Having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to do whatever its implementor decided was appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote some other compiler with such option you can do this.

As answered by @Mats we have another procedure to achieve this is `#ifdef __cplusplus`.
Moreover what you are trying is error only.